# Logic behind where and on generating different outputs in Mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, filtering

Can someone please explain why are these two queries different output. Trying to understand the underlying logic.

Query - 1

```
select u.id,
(count(c.id)) comment_count
from users u
left join comments c
on u.id = c.user_id
and c.created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'
group by 1
order by comment_count desc
```

Query 2

```
select u.id,
(count(c.id)) comment_count
from users u
left join comments c
on u.id = c.user_id
where c.created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'
group by 1
order by comment_count desc
```

Comment: can you show sample output of both queries?

Comment: Sample data and the output you're getting from each of the queries would make this much easier to understand and answer. You may want to read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of sql's sharpest corners and most common errors folks make.

The difference is this condition `c.created_at between '2020-01-01' and '2020-01-31'`

being applied in the JOIN predicate `ON .. AND ...` in the first, but the WHERE predicate in the second.

TLDR - Query 1 actually performs a LEFT JOIN. Query 2 is functionally an INNER JOIN. If you have a filter (on anything but NULL) on Table B in your WHERE clause, it doesn't matter if you type LEFT JOIN, it will still behave like an INNER JOIN.

A rough explanation is that filters applied in the LEFT JOIN clause are applied to the outer table. But filters applied in the WHERE clause are applied to the result of the join. For INNER JOINs this doesn't affect anything, but it's important for LEFT JOINs.

Take this example

```
TableA

a_Key    a_Value
1        A
2        B
3        C

TableB
b_Key    b_Value b_otherValue
1        A       X
2        B       Y
```

So if we join

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA A
  LEFT
  JOIN TableB B
    ON A.a_Key = B.b_Key
   AND A.a_Value = B.b_Value
```

Result set is going to be

```
a_Key a_Value b_Key   b_Value b_otherValue
1     A       1       A       X
2     B       2       B       Y
3     C       NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Because no match was found on {3,C}.

So when we add b_othervalue = 'Y' in the JOIN

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA A
  LEFT
  JOIN TableB B
    ON A.a_Key = B.b_Key
   AND A.a_Value = B.b_Value
   AND B.b_otherValue = 'Y'
```

The result is

```
a_Key a_Value b_Key   b_Value b_otherValue 
1     A       NULL    NULL    NULL
2     B       2       B       Y
3     C       NULL    NULL    NULL
```

However, when the b_othervalue = 'Y' condition is in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT *
  FROM TableA A
  LEFT
  JOIN TableB B
    ON A.a_Key = B.b_Key
   AND A.a_Value = B.b_Value
 WHERE B.b_othervalue = 'Y'
```

We get

```
a_Key a_Value b_Key   b_Value b_otherValue  
2     B       2       B       Y
```

Comment: This was very helpful. 
Thank you so much !